# Transform Tree to have K leaves with minimum cost

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming

I am given a tree and I have to delete nodes to transform tree with k leaves. Each node has a weight associated with it. Deleting the node will cost the associated weight. I want to minimize the cost.

Here is the link to the problem-:http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/online-study-material/topics/dp-trees.php

I am not able to visualize the solution. I need some help. If someone could explain in a broad way or provide some documentation would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea of how you can do it(you may need to modify and add a few things to make it working) -

As explained in the link, we will use a 2d array, say dp, to store our partial answers and use them to find required answer. Secondly, `dp[v][k]` will denote that with root node(of subtree or main tree) **v** we need exactly **k** leaf nodes.

**Base Case -**

For any leaf node lv-

```
//Case 1 - only one leaf is required so we dont need to delete any node
dp[lv][1] = 0

//Case 2 - more than 1 leaf node required which is not possible 
dp[lv][k] = INT_MAX
```

For any node v -

```
//As no leaf is required we delete all nodes
dp[v][0] = sum of weights of all nodes in subtree with v(including weight of v)
```

**Mechanics of DP-**

Now lets say we are at a node **v** presently and we need to have **k** leafs in this node's subtree. Lets write its code first on how to do it and I will explain how it works after that.

```
for(int i=0;i<=k;i++)
    dp[v][k]  =  min( dp[v][k], dp[left-child][i] + dp[right-child][k-i];
```

Here `left-child` and `right-child` are left and right nodes of **v**.

For every leaf node, there are two things that are possible ie it can be in left-subtree or right-subtree. So, I am iterating through all these states starting from left-suubtree containing no leaf node to left-subtree containing all leaf nodes and same for right-subtree. Finally, storing the min value found from iterating in `dp[v][k]`.